# How to alert user while closing the browser in Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, c#

Please suggest a way to alert user while closing the browser in Mozilla firefox. i have tried the onbeforeunload for IE and Chrome and it does work in both. But I am unable to get the same response in Firefox. It seems that onbeforeunload and onunload is not working in Firefox. Also, in some of the blogs I have found that the onbeforeunload only works with Firefox 4.0 or less version. I have tried the below javascript code and it works for me in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
        var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; 

        myEvent(chkevent, function (e) {
            var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';
            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
            return confirmationMessage;
        });

</script>
```

Appreciate, if any alternative is available.

Comment: It's a very very bad practice and ruins user experience. It reminds me of adware and windows/tabs that are difficult to close... Please do not implement it.

Comment: Ok. But I have tried all the alternatives available on the sites and still not able to get the correct result. Please suggest better way to get the possible outcome. Thanks Alex.

Comment: Please refer this Doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload It may help you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Do you want to close?";
};
```

Comment: I have tried all this methods, but still not able to get any possible outcome for firefox.